# How to Create a Printing Method in Python

Tags: python, class, object, printing

I'm fairly new to python and have a little background in c++. I'm just getting my mind around object oriented programming, but I am having a problem defining print methods in this class I created. I have read into both the repr() and str() functions, but neither of them seems to work.

```
class chicken():
    def __init__(self, name, eatable, species):
        self.name=name
        if eatable!="yes" and eatable!="no":
            self.eatable="no"
        else:
            self.eatable=eatable
        self.species=species
    #Print the species when called
    #Doesnt work for some reason
    def print_species(self):
        print "%s" %str(self.species)
    #Print whether or not the bird is eatable
    #This method also doesnt work
    def print_eatable(self):
        print "%s" %str(self.eatable)
    def change_species(self, new_name):
        self.species=new_name
    def change_eatable(self, new_status):
        self.eatable=new_status
        if new_status!="yes" and new_status!="no":
            self.eatable="no"
        else:
            self.eatable=new_status
peep=chicken("Peep", "yes", "Gallus Domesticus")
peep.change_eatable("meatballs")
peep.print_eatable
peep.print_species
#This does work
print peep.eatable
```

Can anyone explain how I can create a method so I can simply print information about the object (ie. peep.print_species="Gallus Domesticus")?

Thanks

Comment: You need parentheses after your function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses at the end of your function calls:

```
peep.print_eatable()
peep.print_species()
```

So code should be:

```
class chicken():
    def __init__(self, name, eatable, species):
        self.name=name
        if eatable!="yes" and eatable!="no":
            self.eatable="no"
        else:
            self.eatable=eatable
        self.species=species
    #Print the species when called
    #Doesnt work for some reason
    def print_species(self):
        print"%s" %str(self.species)
    #Print whether or not the bird is eatable
    #This method also doesnt work
    def print_eatable(self):
        print "%s" %str(self.eatable)
    def change_species(self, new_name):
        self.species=new_name
    def change_eatable(self, new_status):
        self.eatable=new_status
        if new_status!="yes" and new_status!="no":
            self.eatable="no"
        else:
            self.eatable=new_status
peep=chicken("Peep", "yes", "Gallus Domesticus")
peep.change_eatable("meatballs")
peep.print_eatable()
peep.print_species()
#This does work
print peep.eatable
```

Comment: Not at all. We have all been there!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses at the end of your function calls.

```
peep.print_eatable()
peep.print_species()
```

When you code `peep.print_species` without parentheses, Python will not report a syntax error because it is a perfectly legitimate statement that returns the method object `print_species`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *CALL* your methods, not just get them. Put `()` behind your statements:

```
peep=chicken("Peep", "yes", "Gallus Domesticus")
peep.change_eatable("meatballs")
peep.print_eatable()
```